# bash command in shell script(If else erroring out)

Tags: bash, shell

```
    #!/bin/bash

    FILE_NAME=$1
    FILE_LOCATION=$2
    ENTITY_LIST=ALL
    echo "FILE_NAME and location"
    echo $FILE_NAME
    echo $FILE_LOCATION

    if [echo $FILE_NAME | awk -F"_" '{print $3}' = "IMAGE"];
    then

        F_NAME=echo $FILE_NAME | awk -F"_" '{print "UCM_"$3"_"$4}'
    else

        F_NAME=`echo $FILE_NAME | sed 's/FUSION_CONFIGURATION_1/UCM/'`
        exit 0
    fi

# exit 1 represents concurrent program status. 1 for error, 2 for warning 0 for success
echo "***********************************final*****************************"
```

This is giving an error syntax error at line 15 : `fi' unexpected

The if is closed with fi which is the correct syntax. Any suggestion on the error we are getting

Comment: doesn't this line `[echo $FILE_NAME | awk -F"_" '{print $3}' = "IMAGE"];` needs spaces between square brackets and the rest?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I think it needs no square brackets at all.

Comment: You need spaces in line 15. Also, It maybe better if you give a smaller concise example.

Comment: What does `echo $FILE_NAME | awk -F"_" '{print $3}' = "IMAGE"` even meant to do? It is an incorrect synatax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is I think what you want to do

```
 #!/bin/bash
    #Note If you see # in front of any line it means that it’s a comment line not the actual code
    #** ********************************************************************
    # Description :
    #
    #** ********************************************************************

    FILE_NAME=$1
    FILE_LOCATION=$2
    ENTITY_LIST=ALL
    echo "FILE_NAME and location"
    echo $FILE_NAME
    echo $FILE_LOCATION

    if [[ $(echo $FILE_NAME | awk -F"_" '{print $3}') == "IMAGE" ]];
    then

     F_NAME=echo $FILE_NAME | awk -F"_" '{print "UCM_"$3"_"$4}'
    else

    F_NAME=`echo $FILE_NAME | sed 's/FUSION_CONFIGURATION_1/UCM/'`
    exit 0
    fi
```